# Alert in typescript

Tags: typescript, express, alert

how can I display alert box in if sentence in typescript.

```
if (rows.length <= 0) {
            console.log('No rows')
            res.redirect('/lessons')
 ERROR SHOULD DISPLAY IF CODE RUNS THESE ROWS


        }
        else { // if user found
            console.log('Rows found!')´
```

Comment: You already tried putting an `alert(…)` and doesnt work?

Comment: @robertndrei Yes.

Comment: This code is running on `client` or on `server`, is this `express`?

Comment: @robertndrei Its running on server and yes, its express.

Comment: Under nodejs you can only display `console.log`, you cannot display an `alert`. The `alert` is only available on client side. To achieve what you are trying, you should send a message to the client to display the alert and then redirect.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Mybad.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout to redirect the page. try this source code

```
if(rows.length <= 0){
    alert('No rows');
    setTimeout(function() {
       res.redirect('/lessons');
    }, 1000);
}else{
    alert('Rows found!');
}
```

Comment: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'alert'.

Comment: This won't work because it's executed on the server. Hence, `alert` is not known.